# JSON_PRETTY_PRINT and JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES in same argument

Tags: php, json

I am trying to pretty print a json array, AND un-escape slashes at same time, but don't know how...

I've got:

```
<pre><?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?></pre>
```

or

```
<pre><?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); ?></pre>
```

working fine on their own, but can't seem to combine them.

Answer (score 28):

Found out how:

```
<pre><?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?></pre>
```

Read about the PHP [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).